# Códigos para teclas control multimedia

Tags: android, arduino

Estoy intentando con Arduino hacer un "mando" para controlar la música del móvil por BT
Y estoy buscando los códigos de las teclas multimedia pero no los encuentro por ningún lado
Alguien me puede decir dónde encontrarlos o echarme una ayuda.
Necesito principalmente Anterior, Play/Pausa y siguiente

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas esta en el foro de Arduino(ingles) [arduino.stackexchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/25593/want-to-create-bluetooth-audio-control-volume-up-down-play-pause-etc-for-s)

Comment: Si, era esto, gracias :)

Comment: Vale pues luego puedo que intente traducirlo para español